# Postgresql with react usage guide

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I'm new at programming. I want to know how to use my database with react? I can create db and tables with PostgreSql but how to connect from react project? Do we have any guide/tutorial available? I found node-postgres. Is that useful or should I find another thing?

Comment: First you'll need to learn about server-side programming in general. It doesn't even have to be JavaScript. You need to define a HTTP API that your React frontend can talk to, which uses the database internally.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out which questions are on/off-topic. As your question stands now, it needs more clarity & focus on a specific problem..

Answer (score 0):

Frontend and Backend are the two most popular terms used in web development. These terms are very crucial for web development but are quite different from each other. Each side needs to communicate and operate effectively with the other as a single unit to improve the website’s functionality.

---

## BackEnd

Backend is server-side of the website. It stores and arranges data, and also makes sure everything on the client-side of the website works fine. It is the part of the website that you cannot see and interact with. It is the portion of software that does not come in direct contact with the users. The parts and characteristics developed by backend designers are indirectly accessed by users through a front-end application. Activities, like writing APIs, creating libraries, and working with system components without user interfaces or even systems of scientific programming, are also included in the backend.

## FrontEnd

The part of a website that the user interacts with directly is termed as the front end. It is also referred to as the ‘client-side’ of the application. It includes everything that users experience directly: text colors and styles, images, graphs and tables, buttons, colors, and navigation menu. HTML, CSS, and Javascript are the languages used for Front End development. The structure, design, behavior, and content of everything seen on browser screen when websites, web applications, or mobile apps are opened up, is implemented by front End developers. Responsiveness and performance are two main objectives of the FrontEnd. The developer must ensure that the site is responsive i.e. it appears correctly on devices of all sizes no part of the website should behave abnormally irrespective of the size of the screen.

---

## What shall you do

So you've learned to handle Fontend with react but you still need to handle backend but if you didn't know a language to handle it, don't worry.

You can use something like `firebase` and here is its link : [Link](https://firebase.google.com/)

And also you can learn to integrate these 2 sides with this document: [Link](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial)

Good luck